# Существуют ли формальные правила применения возвратных глаголов в обеих частях составного сказуемого?

Tags: грамотная-речь, сказуемые, правила

Например: `После запуска пленки кадры начинают показываться на экране` или `После запуска пленки кадры начинаются показываться на экране`?

Интуитивно мне кажется, что правильным является только первый вариант. Так ли это? И если так, то есть ли какое-то правило, которое явно регулирует этот аспект?

Дополнение: при этом `мне начинает казаться, что ситуация накаляется` и `мне хочется казаться большим и значимым`.

Comment: Часть — слово ж. рода. Исправьте то, что понято интуитивно неверно!

Comment: Да, мне тоже интуитивно кажется, что многие незнаменательные связки в возвратном варианте становятся знаменательными, и следовательно простыми сказуемыми. Но это верно не для всех связок. Для вашей, похоже, верно.

Answer (score 1):

> Разрешается ли использование возвратных глаголов в обеих частях
> составного сказуемого?

Ну а почему бы и нет? См. пример:

***Мне хочется улыбаться, смеяться, радоваться жизни!***

Comment: Да, это хороший и показательный пример. Но тем более интересно было бы разобраться, где оно допустимо, а где нет.